# Data manipulation in cloud environments

Tags: transactions, azure, amazon-s3, cloud, icloud

I have some doubts about accessing and processing data in cloud storage services.

1.Is there any common API that i can use to write applications for the mainstream cloud storage providers(Amazon s3,Google cloud storage,Windows Azure..Please point out providers whom i missed in this list. I am concentrating on Enterprise domain only, not personal storage)

2.Now the sdk part. If i want to write an application(let us say a j2ee application) that process data in iCloud, does iCloud sdk provides me that kind of flexibility?

3.Will the cloud storage service provide me transaction support?I mean support for ACID properties.Or i have to take the responsibility for it?

Answer (score 2):

- [jClouds](http://www.jclouds.org/) offers a good storage abstraction. It supports many of the most commonly used cloud storage providers, including Amazon s3, MS Azure and others. For a list of storage providers, see here: http://www.jclouds.org/documentation/reference/supported-providers

Here is how to use the jClouds storage context:

```
    import static 
        org.jclouds.aws.s3.options.PutObjectOptions.Builder.withAcl;

    // get a context with amazon that offers the portable BlobStore API
    BlobStoreContext context = new BlobStoreContextFactory().
                         createContext("aws-s3", accesskeyid, secretkey);

    // create a container in the default location
    BlobStore blobStore = context.getBlobStore();
    blobStore.createContainerInLocation(null, bucket);

    // add blob
    Blob blob = blobStore.newBlob("test");
    blob.setPayload("test data");
    blobStore.putBlob(bucket, blob);

    // when you need access to s3-specific features,
    // use the provider-specific context
    AWSS3Client s3Client =
         AWSS3Client.class.cast(context.getProviderSpecificContext().getApi());

    // make the object world readable
    String publicReadWriteObjectKey = "public-read-write-acl";
    S3Object object = s3Client.newS3Object();

    object.getMetadata().setKey(publicReadWriteObjectKey);
    object.setPayload("hello world");
    s3Client.putObject(bucket, object, withAcl(CannedAccessPolicy.PUBLIC_READ));

    context.close();
```

- Not really an expert on iCloud, but I got the  impression that it was for use only with the various apple products, and not a generic platform, as was mentioned in a previous answer.
- Cloud storage services generally don't offer ACID properties. What you are looking for sounds more like some of the cloud database services out there - Amazon [SimpleDB](http://aws.amazon.com/simpledb/) and [RDS](http://aws.amazon.com/rds/), MS [SQL Azure](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/home/features/sql-azure/) etc.  You might be able to use a JDBC driver to connect to some of them. But these are not 'storage' services - these are databases running in the cloud, each with its own semantics.

Answer (score 1):

The basis of any Cloud service provider is to use REST interface. You can use any language to wrap REST request as long as the language supports networking and PKI security infrastructure.  All modern language have such functionality.

Any SDK in most cases is just a wrapper to these REST interface so you can very easily write the coder and sync or async way and get what you are looking. SDK just expedite the work to manifold, comparative to using REST directly. That does not mean you can not use REST direclty, it is just an SDK is there to help you to connect to specific cloud service.

How SDK are implemented and what kind of functionality it provides, varies from providder to provider and the services they have. You can not use the Windows Azure SDK for Amazon Cloud because the internal service connection endpoints and underneath interfaces are encapsulated within the SDK itself. It does not mean an SDK can not be created to connect all of the cloud service provide however each cloud service provide individualize the SDK for their cloud service.

Cloud services provide infrastructure and platform your users to deploy their application and about  ACID, you will have to take care of application level work, however ACID could be a totally separate and lengthy discussion..

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your 3 questions:

1. This isn't really a specific programming question, more like a survey of available products. I don't know of any particular libraries that provide a completely generic interface across all cloud providers.
2. iCloud, from my understanding, is for storage and synchronization of your Mac / iPad / iPod content and not a compute platform.
3. I'm sure all cloud providers offer different relational and non-relational data stores, each with its own transaction support (or lack thereof). In Windows Azure, SQL Azure provides ACID support similar to SQL Server, aside from distributed transactions. Windows Azure Table Storage provides atomic operations within a given partition, so as long as your multi-record writes are written to the same partition, this may be done in one atomic operation. SQL Azure, as well as Windows Azure Storage (blobs, tables, and queues) are considered Durable, as storage is triple-replicated for redundancy (and Windows Azure storage is also geo-replicated).

Answer (score 0):

For question 1. If you're asking if all the services you list share a common API, no. They all use REST which means you can use JSON with any of them, but the call will have different names and possibly syntax.

Answer (score -1):

You ca use iClous only through Apple's SDK for iOs and Mac OS X. I am almost sure you cannot access it from a j2ee application.